# 1C: Предприятие Проверка полей перед записью

Tags: 1с

Привет.

Тут есть люди кто шарит в 1С.

Проблема вроде ваще изи(Но к сожалению это надо реализовать на 1С) но 1С такой не хороший.
Есть форма для добавления документа.Хочу при записи сделать проверку.

код

```
&НаКлиенте
Процедура ПередЗаписью(Отказ, ПараметрыЗаписи)

КонецПроцедуры
```

Вся соль в том что нет доступа к тем полям  что в форме при записи

Тот обьект что будет писаться  передаеться как бы  в эту функцию

```
&НаСервере
Процедура ПередЗаписьюНаСервере(Отказ, ТекущийОбъект, ПараметрыЗаписи)

КонецПроцедуры
```

Но в 1С все так муторно что тут банально нельзя сделать оповещение потому что это типа функция выполняется на сервере.

**Вопрос**

Как получить доступ к полям формы на стороне клиента при записи обьекта в базу.

То есть сделать проверку и при необходимости вывести ошибку не соответствия условию записи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> нельзя сделать оповещение потому что это типа функция выполняется на
>   сервере.

Можно. См. в Синтакс-помощнике описание процедуры СообщениеПользователю (UserMessage), она доступна для вызова вообще где угодно.

С клиента поля объекта вы сможете проверить только на заполненность, функцией ЗначениеЗаполнено().

Comment: Думаю в ответе стоит упомянуть, что для проверки заполнения существуют соответствующие события как на сервере так и на клиенте.